# How can I tell if somebody is logged in with Temp Profile?

Tags: windows-xp, user-profiles, temporary-files

I have a user that is logged on but i dont think that their profile has loaded properly.  I click on the start menu and it shows the correct username, but im wondering is there a way (once im logged in) to tell if i am using a temp profile or my normal one?

Comment: is the background the same-my temp is still in the factory setting desktop

Comment: sorry i dont understand?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows Xp pro 32 bit

Comment: just if the desktop looks the same-it happened to me and the desktop was different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows XP:

Right click 'My Computer', goto 'Properties' then on the Advanced tab click [Settings] under User Profiles. This will list all the user profiles on the PC, sizes, date modified etc. Verify you don't have two with similar names or one local and the one you want to use being a roaming profile.

Comment: Just to add another way as well is just to goto `C:\Documents and Settings` if TEMP is listed in that folder same result.

Comment: If Windows cannot load the users profile then it'll login with a 'temp' username, coincidentally this user will have a different desktop background as mentioned by [mic84](http://superuser.com/users/44625/mic84) above :)

Answer (score 0):

Goto start
control panel and then mail, mail setup goto Profiles, show profiles, copy and rename then save and apply changes.

Answer (score -2):

bring up a dos box....type set and hit enter....read the line at the bottom that says USERPROFILE

If it says TEMP then you are logged in with a temp profile

Comment: At SuperUser we appreciate right answers. However, a *great* answer has proper capitalization, a easy to view layout and perhaps a few screenshots. Also a big plus if you can cite resources which describe the functionality you are suggesting.